# 203. Remove Linked List Elements from the leetcode

Tags: java, recursion, singly-linked-list

*This code has to remove the node of the value sent from LinkedList where head and the value is given*
**Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code?**

```
/**
     * Definition for singly-linked list.
     * public class ListNode {
     *     int val;
     *     ListNode next;
     *     ListNode() {}
     *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
     *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
     * }
     */
    class Solution {
        public ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
            if(head==null) return head;
            if(head.val==val) {head=head.next;}
            ListNode currentNode = head;
            ListNode previousNode = head;
            while(currentNode.val!=val) {
                previousNode=currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
            }
            previousNode.next=currentNode.next;
            removeElements(currentNode.next,val);
            return head;
        }
    }
```

**For the test case [7,7,7,7] expected answer is [] but the code is giving the output [7,7,7]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to pass through the list and checking the current node and update the reference if needed

```
public ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
            if(head==null) return null;
            if(head.val==val) return removeElements(head.next,val);
            head.next = removeElements(head.next,val);
            return head;
        }
```